# S3 Lifecycle Policy - Prefix

Tags: s3-lifecycle-policy

Can we apply the rule for multiple folders inside lets consider C3/TempData/ there are multiple folders inside C3/TempData/ can we apply S3 delete lifecycle policy in a single rule, if yes how can we add it in prefix for eg (C3/TempData/247Tasks/   & C3/Tempdata/logs/ etc)

I tried applying s3 lifecycle policy for deletion for multiple folders in a single rule so i gave prefix as below but it did not worked.

prefix - C3/Tepdata/247tasks/,C3/Tempdata/logs/,C3/Tempdata/247logs/